# When I try and import pyqt4 in pycharm it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'"

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, pyqt4, anaconda

I have Anaconda Distribution installed and installed pyqt4 using sourceforge (link below),  but when I try and import pyqt4 in pycharm it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'"

sourceforge link:https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/﻿

I have been looking up tutorial videos on how to develop a basic desktop application and stumbled upon this guy "sentdex" (youtube)

I was attempting to follow his code but was getting errors

his code:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBME1ZyHiP8&t=242s

I know I have pyqt5 with anaconda, but everyone seems to recommend against that version so I tried to install pyqt4 separately so I could work on my project. However, pycharm isn't able to reference it when I try and import PyQt4.

Any help would be amazing. I'm relatively new to coding and very new to GUI not sure what's the best way to learn this stuff.